Plot the graph with labels
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Effect of Positive Checks on Population},
        xlabel={Time},
        ylabel={Population Size},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        grid=major,
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        height=0.5\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {
        (0, 10) (1, 20) (2, 40) (3, 80) (4, 160) (5, 80) (6, 40)
    };
    \legend{Population}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Nice code, but without a description of what is in error or what is desired then it is left with saying "nice code".

Without a lot more context, your question is almost impossible to answer. Furthermore, adding labeled nodes to your plot is something a quick search on the internet would easily solve. Here is an attempt at clairvoyant divination:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Effect of Positive Checks on Population},
        xlabel={Time},
        ylabel={Population Size},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        grid=major,
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        height=0.5\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {
        (0, 10) (1, 20) (2, 40) (3, 80) (4, 160) (5, 80) (6, 40)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Population}

    % Adding labels to each point with offsets
    \node at (axis cs:0,10) [anchor=south east, blue] {10};
    \node at (axis cs:1,20) [anchor=south east, blue, xshift=-2, yshift=2] {20};
    \node at (axis cs:2,40) [anchor=south east, blue, xshift=-5, yshift=0] {40};
    \node at (axis cs:3,80) [anchor=north east, blue, xshift=-7, yshift=5] {80};
    \node at (axis cs:4,160) [anchor=north west, blue, xshift=5, yshift=-5] {160};
    \node at (axis cs:5,80) [anchor=north west, blue, xshift=5, yshift=5] {80};
    \node at (axis cs:6,40) [anchor=north west, blue, xshift=5, yshift=-5] {40};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here's how it looks like:


+1 Nice approach

@MS-SPO Why, thank you!

Here is yet another speculation. Perhaps you wanted axis-option nodes near coords, see manual? Look up nodes near coords style to change those nodes style, if needed. // Search for "nodes near" in ch "Two Dimensional Plot ...".

\documentclass[border=3mm]% <<< if you want some space
                            {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Effect of Positive Checks on Population},
        xlabel={Time},
        ylabel={Population Size},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        grid=major,
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        height=0.5\textwidth,
        nodes near coords,  % <<<
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {
        (0, 10) (1, 20) (2, 40) (3, 80) (4, 160) (5, 80) (6, 40)
    };
    \legend{Population}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

